# I want to check the value entered in Data gridview is already exist or not?

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview

I am trying to validate my datagridview. when i added some data to one row and if i enter some data in another row then it should show a message.
I am trying this following code. A null exception error is thrown.
As the value in particular cell is null.
Its not able to fetch the value.

```
private void dataGridViewBrandDetails_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
                    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex > -1)
        {
        var dgv = sender as DataGridView;
   for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewBrandDetails.Rows.Count; i++)
       {


            string s = dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

           if (dataGridViewBrandDetails.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null && dataGridViewBrandDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == dataGridViewBrandDetails.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
            {

                MessageBox.Show("The value already existed in DataGridView.");


            }

        }   

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change few things :

```
private void dataGridViewBrandDetails_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex > -1)
        {
        var dgv = sender as DataGridView;
        string s = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewBrandDetails.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
           if(i!=e.RowIndex) // To skip the row with newly inserted value
           {
               if (dataGridViewBrandDetails.Rows[i].Cells[0] != null && dataGridViewBrandDetails.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == s
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("The value already existed in DataGridView.");
               }
            }
        }   

        }

    }
```

I have kept your code as it is with few changes. Although there might be few changes that you want to do.
First : make i=1 if your first row is header row and not a row with value. 
Second : if the rows at column 0 contain controls, you should cast them to control and and then read their values.

Comment: in the line with String s .. value is null i dont know y